# Trying to display animation on click....not working (js, html, css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, visibility

I have a loading element that I want to display on the click of a certain button. I have tried various methods including updating the visibility and display, as well as adding a "show" classList to the div onclick (current code). Nothing has worked so far and I am desperate. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks :)

```js
document.getElementById('text-generate-button').onclick = () => {
  parent.postMessage({
    pluginMessage: {
      type: 'placeholder-frame'
    }
  }, '*')
  const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
  loader.classList.add("show")
}
```

```css
.loader {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* background: radial-gradient(#222, #000); */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* z-index: 99999; */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.4);
  transform: scale(0.4);
}

.loader.show {
  background: #ffffff;
  /* background: radial-gradient(#222, #000); */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* z-index: 99999; */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.4);
  transform: scale(0.4);
}

.loader-inner {
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.loader-line-wrap {
  animation: spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100px;
}

.loader-line {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -50ms;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -100ms;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -150ms;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -200ms;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -250ms;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
  border-color: #EB6A6F;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 7px;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
  border-color: #F6BA48;
  height: 76px;
  width: 76px;
  top: 14px;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
  border-color: #B5D643;
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  top: 21px;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
  border-color: #50CFD4;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 28px;
}

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
  border-color: #9665D4;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  top: 35px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%,
  15% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="loader-inner">
      <div class="loader-line-wrap">
        <div class="loader-line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader-line-wrap">
        <div class="loader-line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader-line-wrap">
        <div class="loader-line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader-line-wrap">
        <div class="loader-line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader-line-wrap">
        <div class="loader-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You seem to have both display none and opacity 0 set on loader.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig deep whether there is a better way
but one thing you can do is in your HTML set

```
<div class="loader" id="loader>
```

and in your JS

```
 loader.classList.toggle("loader")
```

here is running version : https://jsbin.com/boromarugo/edit?html,css,js,output

there should be cleaner way but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you. That does work perfectly in the browser, but unfortunately it is not working on my interface. I am building a figma plugin with the figma API (https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/). Do you think this could be affecting the issues with display?